# Livewire 3 wire navigate attribute issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

If I add wire:navigate attribute on a link I have this error when clicking the link :

```
livewire.js?id=f477dd12:7356 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
at extractUriAndQueryString (livewire.js?id=f477dd12:7356:16)
at livewire.js?id=f477dd12:7349:46
at Array.some (<anonymous>)
at ifTheQueryStringChangedSinceLastRequest (livewire.js?id=f477dd12:7346:32)
at mergeNewHead (livewire.js?id=f477dd12:7294:17)
at swapCurrentPageWithNewHtml (livewire.js?id=f477dd12:7265:5)
at livewire.js?id=f477dd12:7429:11
at preventAlpineFromPickingUpDomChanges (livewire.js?id=f477dd12:7480:5)
at livewire.js?id=f477dd12:7425:9
at getPretchedHtmlOr (livewire.js?id=f477dd12:7007:14)
```

In the blade view the code is :

```
<a wire:navigate href="{{ route('login') }}" class="btn btn-primary d-none d-md-flex ms-3">
                Login
            </a>
```

**Important: other links with wire:navigate attribute works but not this one**